# Bookmark page and show in profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

I am working on a SharePoint application and requirement is to provide user an ability to bookmark a page, I have added a bookmark icon in page layout and all pages are showing an icon of left hand side, when user clicks I want to add an entry in a list and when user browse that page again I want to show that this page is already bookmarked, I am using different icons for that.

I want to store all bookmarks in user's profile, I tried to use "QuickLinks" list but CSOM and Rest API is not returning quick links in result.

User can also add some other links in that list, e-g link to gmail account.

Can I create a list to store bookmark information for all users in profile?
When user visits the profile page I have to show that list somewhere on the profile page.
"QuickLinks" would have been the ideal option because there is an Out Of The Box WebPart available to show all quick links but unfortunate I am unable to access "QuickLinks" items.

Any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, then there exist a good CodePlex solution. You find it here: [My Links Menu for SharePoint 2010](http://mylinks.codeplex.com/)

If you are using SharePoint 2013 there exist something called "My Quick Links" which can be found on this url: `http://<webapplication>/_layouts/15/MyQuickLinks.aspx`, where user "bookmarks" are stored.

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013 and I can access "QuickLinks" from the url but I can't get these links through JSOM, I have tried to get with rest service, I got lot of information but "QuickLinks" is always empty. If I get list of quick links on clinet side then I will use JSOM to add new links when user clicks on Bookmark button.